# I am trying to create a code for the exercise below in python (for school) and I am stuck

Tags: python, loops, time

Create a program that will time how long it takes the user to type in the alphabet correctly.  It will not stop the timer until they have correctly typed it in and if they make a mistake it will show a message and they will have to try to type it in again.  Once they have successfully managed to type in the alphabet correctly it will tell them how long it took them and then ask them if they want to try again to see if they can beat their previous time.

I managed to do the first part:

```
import time

starttime = time.time()

def ask_question1():
answer1= input("Type in the alphabet as fast as you can then press enter: ")
return answer1

if __name__=="__main__":
    answer1=ask_question1()
    while answer1 != "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
        print("You made a mistake. ")
        answer1=input("Try again: ")

endtime=time.time()
print("It took you ",round(endtime-starttime, 2), " seconds")
```

but I can't make it ask the question again and repeat the process.

Comment: what's the problem with my answer you mark it as `unaccept`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The `ask_question1` function is not necessary, You can use `input`
   in Python 3 or `raw_input` in Python 2.
2. You didn't need to write `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`, You can use
   `string.lowercase` in Python 2 or `string.ascii_lowercase` in Python
3. You can make a while for ever ;) whit `while True` and use `brake`
   to exit from loop.

Python 2:

```
import time
import string

if __name__=="__main__":
    starttime = time.time()
    answer1 = raw_input("Type in the alphabet as fast as you can then press enter: ")
    while True:
        if answer1 != string.lowercase:
            print("You made a mistake. ")
            answer1 = raw_input("Try again: ")
        else:
            endtime = time.time()
            print("It took you " + str(round(endtime-starttime, 2)) + " seconds")
            break
```

Python 3:

```
import time
import string

if __name__=="__main__":
    starttime = time.time()
    answer1 = input("Type in the alphabet as fast as you can then press enter: ")

    while True:
        if answer1 != string.ascii_lowercase:
            print("You made a mistake. ")
            answer1=input("Try again: ")
        else:
            endtime=time.time()
            print("It took you ",round(endtime-starttime, 2), " seconds")
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to call the `ask_question1` instead of `answer1=input("Try again: ")`

Answer (score 0):

use raw_input() instead of input(), this will return it as a string.

```
import time

starttime = time.time()

def ask_question1():
    return raw_input("Type in the alphabet as fast as you can then press enter: ")

if __name__=="__main__":
    while ask_question1() != "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
        print("You made a mistake. ")

endtime=time.time()
print("It took you ",round(endtime-starttime, 2), " seconds")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work; use `raw_input` and call function recursively.

```
import time

starttime = time.time()

def ask_question1():
    answer1= raw_input("Type in the alphabet as fast as you can then press enter: ")
    return answer1

if __name__=="__main__":
    answer1=ask_question1()
    while answer1 != "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
        print("You made a mistake. ")
        answer1=ask_question1()

    endtime=time.time()
    print("It took you ",round(endtime-starttime, 2), " seconds")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

starttime = time.time()

def ask_question1():
    return raw_input("Type in the alphabet as fast as you can then press enter: ")

if __name__=="__main__":
    while ask_question1() != "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
        print("You made a mistake.Try again: ")

endtime=time.time()
print("It took you ",round(endtime-starttime, 2), " seconds")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

starttime = time.time()

def ask_question1():
    answer1= input("Type in the alphabet as fast as you can then press enter: ")
return answer1

def check_answer():
    if __name__=="__main__":
        answer1=ask_question1()
        while answer1 != "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
            print("You made a mistake. ")
            answer1=input("Try again: ")
return

endtime=time.time()
print("It took you ",round(endtime-starttime, 2), " seconds")
again=raw_input("Do you want to try again (Y/N):")
if again=="Y":
    check_answer()
```

You can try something like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
starttime = time.time()

def ask_question1():
    answer1= raw_input("Type in the alphabet as fast as you can then 
press enter: ")
    return replying_question1(answer1)

def replying_question1(answer):
    while answer in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
        endtime=time.time()
        print("It took you ",round(endtime-starttime, 2), " seconds")
        return round(endtime-starttime, 2)
    print("You made a mistake. ")
    ask_question1()
if __name__=="__main__":
    ask_question1()
```

and the output will be :
for failure :

```
Type in the alphabet as fast as you can then press enter: 3
You made a mistake.
```

for correct :

```
Type in the alphabet as fast as you can then press enter: e
('It took you ', 3.32, ' seconds')
```

instead of raw_input u can use use input() only if u r using python 3.